# Kubernetes Job can't reach service right away

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have a `Job` that connects to a running MySQL database and executes some commands:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: do-db-stuff
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: do-db-stuff
        image: mysql:5
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "mysql -h db -uroot -pmypassword mydb -Bse 'show tables;'"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 10
```

This job spins on a crash loop, with each pod reporting: `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (11)`. If I change the command to `["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 3600"]` and log in, I can connect from the `Job`'s pod to the database with the command `mysql -h db -uroot -pmypassword mydb -Bse 'show tables;'` just fine. Based on this, I changed the command in the job to

```yaml
args: ["-c", "sleep 3 && mysql -h db -uroot -pmypassword mydb -Bse 'show tables;'"]`
```

and now it works (i.e. correctly prints out the db tables instead of the unknown host error above). My question is why does the `sleep 3` do anything? The service and database are not changing in the background at all, so why does waiting in the `Job`'s pod make it connect?

Comment: In my opinion `sleep` command shouldn't have any impact in this case.
How did you deploy `mysql` instance ? Is it running on Kubernetes ?

Comment: Yes, it's also running in Kubernetes behind a service called `db`

Comment: Is the mysql instance in the same namespace as this failed Job?
Is it possible for you to change hostname from `db` to `db.default.svc` (service_name.namespace_name.svc) in mysql command and try again ?
Can you provide more information about mysql instance, how did you deploy it (e.g. `kubectl describe` output etc.) ?